# Import new scss file using vue js 2

Tags: laravel, vuejs2

I had issue on importing a new `.scss` to a whole new page template vue which has different from the main scss file. I found this [link](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/issues/328) but still my new styles won't work. By the way, I use laravel 5.4.

**New vue component:**

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
   @import "~sass/new"; //new scss file from resources/sass directory
</style>
```

I think I miss a library to install or what. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check if you have installed 'sass-loader' 'node-sass' 'style-loader'

if not then install it using below command

```
npm install sass-loader node-sass style-loader --save-dev
```

See if you package.json is similar to this

```
"devDependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.1.1",
    "sass-loader": "^3.2.3",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1"
    "vue-loader": "^9.0.0",
    "vue-router": "^2.1.1",
    "webpack": "^1.12.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.12.0"
}
```

Then you can try

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
  @import 'main.scss'
</style>
```

This article must be helpful to you [Using SASS/SCSS in Vue.js 2](https://medium.com/@mahesh.ks/using-sass-scss-in-vue-js-2-d472af0facf9)

Comment: It's weird, It's working now when removing the `scoped` attribute.